# Connect API V2 ListCatalog - Filter by Location ID

Tags: http, square, square-connect

In Connect API V1 to get the List of Items, we would pass `location_id` in the url to pass get the Catalog List for the specific location.

In V2, we only pass the `access_token`, to get the CatalogList, however we get we get the entire CatalogList for all the different locations if a merchant has multiple locations.

Is there a way to pull the Catalog List by location in V2? Otherwise, I would filter the response that is sent back from the API, and my concern would be that it could take a large amount of time upfront to filter the catalog.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot filter your item catalog by `location_id`, as an item catalog is associated with an account, not a location. If you are concerned about the processing time, you could cache the list of ids associated with each location and just do [BatchRetrieveCatalogObjects](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-batchretrievecatalogobjects) instead.

See the [documentation for List Catalog](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-listcatalog) for more details.